# Ho do I extract a Outlook message nested into another using Apache POI - HSMF?

Tags: java, outlook, apache-poi

I am using Apache POI - HSMF to extract attachments from Outlooks msg-files. It works fine except for nested messages. If an msg is attached to another msg I am able to get the files. If a message is nested I get the information but I need the file.

```
MAPIMessage msg = new MAPIMessage(fileName)
for(AttachmentChunks attachment : msg.getAttachmentFiles()) {
    if(attachment.attachmentDirectory!=null){
        MAPIMessage nestedMsg attachment.attachmentDirectory.getAsEmbededMessage();
        // now save nestedMsg as a msg-file
    }
}
```

Is it possible to save the nested message file as a regular msg-file?

Comment: Did you try grabbing the directory, using EntryUtils to write it into a new POIFSFileSystem instance, then read that?

Comment: `EntryUtils.copyNodes` copies either `POIFSFileSystem` to `POIFSFileSystem` or `DirectryNode` to `DirectoryNode`. A version that converts a `DirectoryNode` to a `POIFSFileSystem` is missing. I've also seen that `MAPIMessage.write(OutputStream out)` is not yet implemented. Could it bee that the functionality is just not implemented?

Comment: Create a new POIFSFileSystem, grab the root directory. Use EntryUtils to copy the embedded message directory to the root of the new POIFSFileSytem, then write that new POIFS out to a new file. Finally, see if Outlook like it...

Answer (score 4):

Promoting a comment to an answer. I can tell you how to extract out an embedded Outlook Message to a new file, which Apache POI will then happily open. What I'm less sure on is if an embedded message contains everything that Outlook expects to find in a standalone message, so I can't promise that the resulting file will open with Outlook without issues...

First up, embedded resources in Outlook. Depending on the kind of thing it is, it might be stored in a regular byte chunk, in some other kind of special chunk (eg compress RTF), or it might be a self contained sub-directory in the file. Embedded messages are stored in the latter way.

If you want to extract out an embedded message, what you'll want to do is create a new OLE2 file container, using `POIFSFileSystem` (all Outlook messages are stored in OLE2 containers). Then, you'll want to copy the contents of the embedded message's directory in the source OLE2 container into the root of the new one. Finally, write out that POIFSFileSystem to a new file, and your extraction is complete!

You'll likely want to do something like:

```
 MAPIMessage msg = new MAPIMessage(new NPOIFSFileSytem(new File("test.msg")));
 if (msg.attachmentChunks != null) {
    int number = 0;
    for (AttachmentChunk att : msg.attachmentChunks) {
        if (att.attachmentDirectory != null) {
           number++;
           POIFSFileSystem newMsg = new POIFSFileSystem();
           EntryUtils.copyNodes( att.attachmentDirectory, newMsg.getRoot() );
           FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream("embedded-" + number + ".msg");
           newMsg.write(out);
           out.close();
        }
    }
 }
```

If Outlook has a sulk, try opening the source file in Outlook, saving the embedded message to a new file, and then using the likes of `org.apache.poi.poifs.dev.POIFSLister` and `org.apache.poi.poifs.dev.POIFSDump` to compare the outlook-extracted and POI-extracted files, and see if you can spot any changes that outlook does....

Comment: You are right. With some small modifications I was able to run the code and get a OLE2 container. But as you said, it is no valid Outlook msg file. Using POIFSDump i figured out, that the namedIdChunks are missing. Since they are not contained in the attachment chunks. They get generated by outlook when a message is extracted.

Comment: Can you copy over the ones from the parent file?

Comment: I tried it. Extending the `MAPIMessage` class I managed to copy the nameId entries. The structure of my files is the same but the binary contend differs. Outlook still does not like the file. So this way does not work.

Comment: Did you ever publish you additions? It would be _really_ nice to see a `AttachmentChunk.saveAsOutlookMsg(OutputStream target)` or similar in apache POI

Comment: @GameScripting It needs someone to spend some time saving attachments out with Outlook, then comparing the Outlook-saved ones to POI-extracted ones, and coming up with the list of changes POI needs to do to a file to make it valid. Until someone interested spends the time digging through to work that out, the feature can't be implemented :(

Comment: Ups, just realized @Jan said it DID NOT work. Dumb me. Sorry.

Answer (score 4):

The code in `TestExtractEmbeddedMSG.java` is a little outdated. It’s OK for the unit test but further investigation into this that extracting attached MSG files is a little simpler.

Basically the extraction of an embedded MSG file needs a special treatment as the embedded MSG is not a simple BLOB but it is just a sub-directory in the whole structured storage container. That sub-directory contains all things which make the embedded MSG except two things I know so far:

- The sub-directory does not contain any “name id” property entries (mapping of non-fixed MAPI properties which are scoped by its property set id) which is defined globally once for the whole structured storage
- The binary format of the properties stream is a little different to the top-level one, it misses 8 bytes of reserved data (I don’t know for what reason Microsoft did that but it’s according to the docs).

For that to convert the embedded MSG sub-directory to a top-level one, the top-level “name id” properties need to be copied into the new MSG (this optionally could be optimized that only entries which are really referenced by the embedded MSG are copied, but for that all “name id” entries  need to be parsed and re-built with the really referenced ones) and the properties stream has to be re-build with additional 8 bytes of reserved data.

Here is how I do it now.
`rootmsg` is the file system root of the top-level MSG and `attachedmsg` is the file system root of the embedded MSG which can be obtained by calling `getDirectory` on a `MAPIMessage` object.
The embedded `MAPIMessage` object ca be retrieved by calling `getEmbeddedMessage` on the `AttachmentChunks` object.

Build structured storage file system:

```
  private static POIFSFileSystem rebuildMessageToStream(DirectoryNode rootmsg, DirectoryNode attachedmsg) throws Exception
  {
    //
    // Create new MSG file system and copy all entries.
    //
    POIFSFileSystem newDoc = new POIFSFileSystem();
    //
    // Copy nameid entries from root message.
    //
    if (rootmsg != null) {
      for (Entry entry : rootmsg) {
        if (entry.getName().startsWith(NameIdChunks.NAME)) {
          EntryUtils.copyNodeRecursively(entry, newDoc.getRoot());
        }
      }
    }
    //
    // Copy entries from origin message.
    //
    for (Entry entry : attachedmsg) {
      if (entry.getName().startsWith(PropertiesChunk.NAME) && entry.isDocumentEntry()) {
        if (rootmsg != null) {
          //
          // Rebuild properties stream: Add additional 8 reserved bytes
          // to convert embedded message properties stream to root message properties stream.
          //
          // See MessagePropertiesChunk.writeHeaderData
          //
          DocumentEntry d = (DocumentEntry)entry;
          DocumentInputStream dstream = new DocumentInputStream(d);
          ByteArrayOutputStream rootps = new ByteArrayOutputStream(d.getSize() + 8);
          //
          // Copy first 8 bytes of reserved zeros plus 16 bytes for recipient/attachment counter.
          //
          byte[] data = new byte[24];
          dstream.readFully(data);
          rootps.write(data);
          //
          // Additional 8 bytes of reserved zeros.
          //
          rootps.write(new byte[8]);
          //
          // Properties (remaining data).
          //
          IOUtils.copy(dstream, rootps);
          //
          // Create properties stream entry.
          //
          newDoc.getRoot().createDocument(entry.getName(), new ByteArrayInputStream(rootps.toByteArray()));
          dstream.close();
        }
        else {
          //
          // Copy properties stream unmodified.
          //
          EntryUtils.copyNodeRecursively(entry, newDoc.getRoot());
        }
      }
      else {
        //
        // Copy other entry.
        //
        EntryUtils.copyNodeRecursively(entry, newDoc.getRoot());
      }
    }
    return newDoc;
  }
```

Serialize structured storage:

```
        try (POIFSFileSystem extractedAttachedMsg = rebuildMessageToStream(rootmsg, attachedmsg)) {
            try (ByteArrayOutputStream extractedAttachedMsgOut = new ByteArrayOutputStream()) {
                extractedAttachedMsg.writeFilesystem(extractedAttachedMsgOut);
                byte[] extratedAttachedMsgRaw = extractedAttachedMsgOut.toByteArray();
                // this byte array can be persisted to disk and opened in MS Outlook
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 2):

I 've added some necessary functionality for this to POI and a unit test which extracts an embedded MSG which can be opened in Outlook.
Probably handling of named id properties is not complete (this is not relevant for the unit test verifying my enhancements).

https://svn.apache.org/viewvc/poi/trunk/src/scratchpad/testcases/org/apache/poi/hsmf/TestExtractEmbeddedMSG.java?view=markup

Example from the unit test:

Get the attached MSG

```
MAPIMessage attachedMsg = attachments[0].getEmbeddedMessage();
```

Method for rebuilding the attached MSG

```
private POIFSFileSystem rebuildFromAttached(MAPIMessage attachedMsg) throws IOException {
    // Create new MSG and copy properties.
    POIFSFileSystem newDoc = new POIFSFileSystem();
    MessagePropertiesChunk topLevelChunk = new MessagePropertiesChunk(null);
    // Copy attachments and recipients.
    int recipientscount = 0;
    int attachmentscount = 0;
    for (Entry entry : attachedMsg.getDirectory()) {
        if (entry.getName().startsWith(RecipientChunks.PREFIX)) {
            recipientscount++;
            DirectoryEntry newDir = newDoc.createDirectory(entry.getName());
            for (Entry e : ((DirectoryEntry) entry)) {
                EntryUtils.copyNodeRecursively(e, newDir);
            }
        } else if (entry.getName().startsWith(AttachmentChunks.PREFIX)) {
            attachmentscount++;
            DirectoryEntry newDir = newDoc.createDirectory(entry.getName());
            for (Entry e : ((DirectoryEntry) entry)) {
                EntryUtils.copyNodeRecursively(e, newDir);
            }
        }
    }
    // Copy properties from properties stream.
    MessagePropertiesChunk mpc = attachedMsg.getMainChunks().getMessageProperties();
    for (Map.Entry<MAPIProperty, PropertyValue> p : mpc.getRawProperties().entrySet()) {
        PropertyValue val = p.getValue();
        if (!(val instanceof ChunkBasedPropertyValue)) {
            MAPIType type = val.getActualType();
            if (type != null && type != Types.UNKNOWN) {
                topLevelChunk.setProperty(val);
            }
        }
    }
    // Create nameid entries.
    DirectoryEntry nameid = newDoc.getRoot().createDirectory(NameIdChunks.NAME);
    // GUID stream
    nameid.createDocument(PropertiesChunk.DEFAULT_NAME_PREFIX + "00020102", new ByteArrayInputStream(new byte[0]));
    // Entry stream
    nameid.createDocument(PropertiesChunk.DEFAULT_NAME_PREFIX + "00030102", new ByteArrayInputStream(new byte[0]));
    // String stream
    nameid.createDocument(PropertiesChunk.DEFAULT_NAME_PREFIX + "00040102", new ByteArrayInputStream(new byte[0]));
    // Base properties.
    // Attachment/Recipient counter.
    topLevelChunk.setAttachmentCount(attachmentscount);
    topLevelChunk.setRecipientCount(recipientscount);
    topLevelChunk.setNextAttachmentId(attachmentscount);
    topLevelChunk.setNextRecipientId(recipientscount);
    // Unicode string format.
    byte[] storeSupportMaskData = new byte[4];
    PropertyValue.LongPropertyValue storeSupportPropertyValue = new PropertyValue.LongPropertyValue(MAPIProperty.STORE_SUPPORT_MASK,
            MessagePropertiesChunk.PROPERTIES_FLAG_READABLE | MessagePropertiesChunk.PROPERTIES_FLAG_WRITEABLE,
            storeSupportMaskData);
    storeSupportPropertyValue.setValue(0x00040000);
    topLevelChunk.setProperty(storeSupportPropertyValue);
    topLevelChunk.setProperty(new PropertyValue(MAPIProperty.HASATTACH,
            MessagePropertiesChunk.PROPERTIES_FLAG_READABLE | MessagePropertiesChunk.PROPERTIES_FLAG_WRITEABLE,
            attachmentscount == 0 ? new byte[] { 0 } : new byte[] { 1 }));
    // Copy properties from MSG file system.
    for (Chunk chunk : attachedMsg.getMainChunks().getChunks()) {
        if (!(chunk instanceof MessagePropertiesChunk)) {
            String entryName = chunk.getEntryName();
            String entryType = entryName.substring(entryName.length() - 4);
            int iType = Integer.parseInt(entryType, 16);
            MAPIType type = Types.getById(iType);
            if (type != null && type != Types.UNKNOWN) {
                MAPIProperty mprop = MAPIProperty.createCustom(chunk.getChunkId(), type, chunk.getEntryName());
                ByteArrayOutputStream data = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
                chunk.writeValue(data);
                PropertyValue pval = new PropertyValue(mprop, MessagePropertiesChunk.PROPERTIES_FLAG_READABLE
                        | MessagePropertiesChunk.PROPERTIES_FLAG_WRITEABLE, data.toByteArray(), type);
                topLevelChunk.setProperty(pval);
            }
        }
    }
    topLevelChunk.writeProperties(newDoc.getRoot());
    return newDoc;
}
```

Rebuild the attached MSG

```
            try (POIFSFileSystem extractedAttachedMsg = rebuildFromAttached(attachedMsg)) {
                try (ByteArrayOutputStream extractedAttachedMsgOut = new ByteArrayOutputStream()) {
                    extractedAttachedMsg.writeFilesystem(extractedAttachedMsgOut);
                    byte[] extratedAttachedMsgRaw = extractedAttachedMsgOut.toByteArray();
                    // this byte array can be persisted to disk and opened in MS Outlook
                }
            }
```

Regards,
Dominik

Comment: This solution is a little outdated.

Comment: I have posted a new answere with the current solution.

Comment: could you please tell me the new answer?

Comment: See my latest answere to this question